# Programa para contar las vocales de una cadena

Tags: python, funciones, contador

> "Realice una función de nombre contar_vocales() que reciba como argumento una cadena cualquiera y devuelva la cantidad de vocales presentes en la cadena."

```
def contar_vocales(x):
    voc=0
    for i in len(cad):
        if cad[i]=='a' or cad[i]=='e'or cad[i]=='i' or cad[i]=='o' or cad[i]=='u' or cad[i]=='A'or cad[i]=='E' or cad[i]=='I' or cad[i]=='O'or cad[i]=='U':
            voc=voc+1
        return voc


cad = raw_input('')
print contar_vocales(cad)
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me dice ***"iteration over non-sequence"*** en las lineas 5 y 14.

Intenté resolverlo de varias formas, pero estoy lejos de poder solucionarlo.

Pensando un poco más llegué a este programa, pero no cuenta las vocales, sino qe pone:

> 0
>   0
>   etc

```
#FUNCIONES

def contar_vocales(x):
    contador=0
    total=0
    for letra in c:
        if 'a' in c:
            contador=+1
        if 'e' in c:
            contador=+1
        if 'i' in c:
            contador=+1
        if 'o' in c:
            contador=+1
        if 'u' in c:
            contador=+1
            total=contador
    return total

#PROG. PPAL

c=str('mi cadena')
print contar_vocales(c)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estas haciendo una mezcla de un `for in` con indexación (usando `range`) para recorrer la cadena. Debes elegir una u otra forma, aunque la opción más eficiente y legible es usar `for in`. Por otro lado el  `return` debe estar fuera del `for`. Simplemente debes hacer:

```
def contar_vocales(cad):
    voc = 0
    for c in cad:
        if c == 'a' or c == 'e' or c == 'i' or c =='o' or c == 'u' or c == 'A' or c == 'E' or c == 'I' or c =='O' or c == 'U':
            voc=voc+1
    return voc


cad = raw_input('')
print contar_vocales(cad)
```

Otra opción es usar `in` en el condicional, por ejemplo:

```
def contar_vocales(cad):
    voc = 0
    for c in cad:
        if c in "aeiouAEIOU":
            voc = voc + 1
    return voc
```

U otra opción más eficiente usando `sum` e iteradores y un conjunto:

```
def contar_vocales(cad):
    return sum(c in {"a", "A", "e", "E", "i", "I", "o", "O", "u", "U"} for c in cad)
```

Ten en cuenta que no cuentas vocales con tilde u otros acentos.

Comment: Tienes razón, aún así algo falla, porque en el caso de "Mi cAdena" como acabo de probar recién imprime un 0 y luego ya si el 4 que corresponde a las vocales...

Comment: @Luu he editado la respuesta, no me di cuenta que el return estaba también fuera de lugar. Mira ahora a ver.

Comment: Ahora si, sea la cadena que sea es correcto. Es un problema de la plataforma que me piden usar el que siga saliendo un cero antes que el 4

Answer (score 2):

FJSevilla dio [una excelente respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114786/127) que explica el problema de fondo, como siempre. Me pareció que podía complementar con 2 opciones más:

**Con [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)**:

Generamos un iterador sobre cada vocal con [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), contando cada vocal en el texto, y luego sumamos el total de cada vocal.

```
def contar_vocales(texto):
    return sum(map(texto.lower().count, "aeiouáéíóúü"))
```

**Con una expresión regular:**

Utilizar [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) para esto puede ser demasiado, pero si ya se utiliza en otra parte del código, me gusta como queda. [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) devuelve todas las coincidencias de la expresión regular en el texto como una lista, que luego contamos con [len()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len).

```
import re

def contar_vocales(texto):
    return len(re.findall("[aeiouáéíóíúü]", texto, re.IGNORECASE))
```

- `[aeiouáéíóíúü]` es una clase de caracteres. Es decir, que coincide con uno de los caracteres incluidos dentro de los corchetes.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando tu estilo creo que olvidaste que el return debe ir fuera del `for` y que los for se utilizan con un rango

```
def contar_vocales(x):
    voc=0
    for i in range(0,len(cad)):
        if cad[i]=='a' or cad[i]=='e'or cad[i]=='i' or cad[i]=='o' or \
        cad[i]=='u' or cad[i]=='A'or cad[i]=='E' or cad[i]=='I' or \
        cad[i]=='O'or cad[i]=='U':
            voc=voc+1
    return voc
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor forma de implementarlo es asi

```
extrn ExitProcess : PROC

.data
    cadena DB 'cadena para sacar vocales', 0
    Completo DB 0
.code

longitud PROC
    pop r15
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov rdi, [rsp]+8
    mov r12, 0

    recorrer:
        mov bl, [rdi]
        cmp bl, 0
        je salir

        cmp bl, 61h ; vocal a
        je sumar

        cmp bl, 65h ; vocal e
        je sumar

        cmp bl, 69h ; vocal i
        je sumar

        cmp bl, 6Fh ; vocal o
        je sumar

        cmp bl, 75h ; vocal u
        je sumar


        inc rdi
        jmp recorrer

    sumar:
        inc r12
        inc rdi
        jmp recorrer

    salir:
        pop rbp
        push r12
        push r15
        ret
longitud ENDP

inicio PROC

    lea r13, cadena
    push r13
    call longitud
    pop rax
    call ExitProcess
inicio ENDP

end
```

Comment: Diría que esto no es python :P