# ¿Como puedo hacer para contar las vocales que hay en una palabra?

Tags: python, bucle-for

el programa me pide que al ingresar una palabra cuente las vocales que esta posea de la siguiente manera

a tiene tantas
e tiene tantas
i tiene tantas
o tiene tantas
u tiene tantas

```
        caracter=input("ingrese una palabra: ")

        vocales = "aeiou"

        letra = caracter.count("a")
        letra1 = caracter.count("e")
        letra2 = caracter.count("i")
        letra3 = caracter.count("o")
        letra4 = caracter.count("u")


        for i in vocales:
            if letra > 0:
                print(i)
```

como ven no se como hacer para colocar la cantidad despues de la vocal

ejemplo:

banana

a tiene 3 vocales
e no tiene vocales
i no tiene vocales
o no tiene vocales
u no tiene vocales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes elegir una u otra forma, aunque la opción más eficiente y legible es usar `for in`. Por otro lado el `return` debe estar fuera del `for`. Simplemente debes hacer:

```
ini = True

while ini:
    res = input('Escribe algo y se contarÃƒÂ¡n las vocales ')
    a = res.count('a')
    e = res.count('e')
    i = res.count('i')
    o = res.count('o')
    u = res.count('u')
    print('Tu enunciado tiene:\n', str(a),
          'a\'s\n', str(e), 'e\'s\n', str(i), 'i\'s\n',
          str(o), 'o\'s\n', str(u), 'u\'s\n')
    a = input('Otra ves? ')
    a = ''.join(a.split())
    if a.lower().startswith('s'):
        ini = True
    else:
        ini = False
```

Te recomiendo ver esta pregunta: [Programa para contar las vocales de una cadena](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114782/programa-para-contar-las-vocales-de-una-cadena)

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene un entrada para colocar la palabra que vas a contar las vocales ```input```