# Me sale error en un programa que estoy realizando en Python. Me sale que no estoy definiendo la función

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo este código pero me sale error al final. ¿Qué puedo hacer para evitarlo? Se supone que mi código debe de decir si el nombre que se escoge es compatible con el apellido. para ello están los siguientes criterios:

1. Ambos nombre y apellido tienen la misma cantidad de letras ---> 10 ptos.
2. Ambos nombre y apellido empiezan con una vocal o ambos empiezan con una consonante ---> 5 ptos.
3. Ambos nombre y apellido tienen el mismo número de vocales ---> 10 ptos.
4. Ambos nombre y apellido terminan con la exacta misma letra ---> 20 ptos.

Mientras más puntos obtenga, más compatible es el nombre.

Si pude hacer el criterio 1. Ahora estoy tratando de programar el criterio 2 pero me sale que no he definido una función. Necesito contar las vocales y consonantes del nombre y apellido que ingrese el usuario.

```
print('Ingrese los cinco nombres que le gustan para su bebé:')
nom1= input('1.' )
nom2= input('2.' )
nom3= input('3.' )
nom4= input('4.' )
nom5= input('5.' )
apellido = input('Ingrese el apellido del bebé:')

print ('---------menú-----------')
print ('1.', nom1, apellido)
print ('2.', nom2, apellido)
print ('3.', nom3, apellido)
print ('4.', nom4, apellido)
print ('5.', nom5, apellido)
print ('------------------------')

opcion = input('Escoja un nombre para calcular la compatibilidad:')

#Criterio 1

puntos1 = 0
def fun1(nom1, apellido):
        if len(str(nom1)) == len(str(apellido)):
            return 10
        else:
            return 0
    
puntos1 += fun1(nom1, apellido)


puntos1 = (fun1(nom1, apellido))
print(puntos1, 'puntos')

#Criterio 2

puntos12 = 0

def fun2(nom1, apellido):
    voc = 'aeiou'
    for voc in (nom1, apellido):
        count(voc)

puntos12 += fun2(nom1, apellido)
puntos12 = (fun2(nom1, apellido))
print(puntos12, 'puntos')
```

Comment: ¿Qué se supone hace la función `count`?

Answer (score 1):

El problema te está apareciendo en las líneas:

```
for voc in (nom1, apellido):
    count(voc)
```

Cuando intenta hacer `count(voc)` no encuentra una función definida con ese nombre y te salta el error.

De todas formas, puesto que a todos los criterios les vas vas a pasar el nombre y el apellido, podrías hacer lo siguiente (te pongo solo la estructura general):

```
def calcula_puntos(nombre,apellido):
    puntos = 0  #Empieza cada vez con 0 puntos
    if len(nombre) == len(apellido):  #Este te lo pongo que ya lo tenías resuelto (ya son string, no necesitas convertirlos)
        puntos += 10
    si cumple criterio 2:
        puntos += 5
    si cumple criterio 3:
        puntos += 10
    si cumple criterio 4:
        puntos += 20
    return puntos
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Esta estructura es más simple y ordenanada. Sigo con la misma duda, ¿que función debo de utilizar para contar las vocales y las consonantes?

Comment: No hay una función propia de Python para eso, tendrás que creartela. Puedes mirar por ejemplo aquí: [contar vocales en una cadena](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114782/programa-para-contar-las-vocales-de-una-cadena)

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido Ernesto c:

Tu error se debe a, como dijo Adrian en su respuesta, que la función `count` NO existe.
Viendo el comentario que hiciste allí, veo que tu duda es como puedes saber la cantidad de vocales de la palabra.

El criterio 2 debe revisar si ambos nombres empiezan por una vocal o una consonante, por lo que no te sirve saber la cantidad de vocales que tienen el nombre y el apellido.
Sin embargo, lo vas a necesitar saber en el criterio 3, que te pide que el nombre y el apellido tengan la misma cantidad de vocales.

Podrías usar la siguiente función usando comprensión de listas:

```
def cant_vocales(palabra):
    return sum(1 for letra in palabra.lower() if(letra in "aeiouáéíóú"))
```

U obtendrías el mismo resultado con el método "normal":

```
def cant_vocales(palabra):
    # Inicio la variable vocales en 0
    vocales = 0

    # proceso cada letra de la palabra
    for letra in palabra.lower():
        # Si la letra es una vocal, sumo 1 a vocales, indicando así que encontré una vocal.
        if(letra in "aeiouáéíóú"):
            vocales += 1

    # devuelvo la cantidad de vocales que hay en la palabra
    return vocales
```

Bueno, estas son funciones que te dirán el número de vocales que tiene una palabra. El resto es tarea para la casa ;)