# TypeError: cant_vocales() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo este código pero me sale error al final. ¿Qué puedo hacer para evitarlo? Se supone que mi código debe de decir si el nombre que se escoge es compatible con el apellido. para ello están los siguientes criterios:

1. Ambos nombre y apellido tienen la misma cantidad de letras ---> 10 ptos.
2. Ambos nombre y apellido empiezan con una vocal o ambos empiezan con una consonante ---> 5 ptos.
3. Ambos nombre y apellido tienen el mismo número de vocales ---> 10 ptos.
4. Ambos nombre y apellido terminan con la exacta misma letra ---> 20 ptos.

Mientras más puntos obtenga, más compatible es el nombre.

Si pude hacer el criterio 1. Ahora estoy tratando de programar el criterio 2 pero me sale esto: TypeError: cant_vocales() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.  Necesito contar las vocales y consonantes del nombre y apellido que ingrese el usuario. Hasta el momento solo he realizado las funciones para el nombre 1. Cuando termine todas las copiaré y las aplicaré en cada nombre.

```
nom1 = []
nom2 = []
nom3 = []
nom4 = []
nom5 = []
apellido = [] 

print('Ingrese los cinco nombres que le gustan para su bebé:')
nom1= input('1.' )
nom2= input('2.' )
nom3= input('3.' )
nom4= input('4.' )
nom5= input('5.' )
apellido = input('Ingrese el apellido del bebé:')

#Criterio 1
puntos1 = 0
def fun1(nom1, apellido):
        if len(str(nom1)) == len(str(apellido)):
            return 10
        else:
            return 0
    
puntos1 += fun1(nom1, apellido)


puntos1 = (fun1(nom1, apellido))
print(puntos1, 'puntos')   

 #Criterio 2

def cant_vocales(nom1):
    # Inicio la variable vocales en 0
    vocales = 0

    # proceso cada letra de la palabra
    for letra in nom1.lower():
        # Si la letra es una vocal, sumo 1 a vocales, indicando así que encontré una vocal.
        if(letra in "aeiouáéíóú"):
            vocales += 1

    # devuelvo la cantidad de vocales que hay en la palabra
    return vocales
```

Comment: Pareciera ser que estás llamando el método `cant_vocales` con dos argumentos.. Algo como `cant_vocales("Ernesto","Salvador")` en vez de `cant_vocales("Ernesto Salvador")`. Tu método solo acepta un parámetro de entrada (`nom1`)

Comment: También es posible (aunque no lo creo en este caso, dado el código que muestras) que `cant_vocales()` sea en reaalidad un método de una clase, y que hayas olvidado declarar su parámetro `self`.

Comment: Esa funcion no es un metodo de una clase @abulafia. Lo se por que yo le hice esa función.

Comment: Me parece por lo que has puesto en otras preguntas similares, que has debido poner `cant_vocales(nombre,apellido)`. Cuando lo que tendrías que comprobar (eso si, para el criterio 3, no el 2) es `cant_vocales(nombre) == cant_vocales(apellido)`.

Comment: Nuevamente gracias Adrián. Soy nuevo programando y por eso me confundo mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu pregunta usa la función que te cree en la respuesta de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/437971/me-sale-error-en-un-programa-que-estoy-realizando-en-python-me-sale-que-no-esto/438011#438011).

Cuando te hice esa función, lo hice pensando en que le pases una palabra por vez.
Insisto nuevamente en que no le veo sentido a saber la cantidad de vocales durante el criterio 2.

De cualquier modo, aquí te muestro un ejemplo de como pensaba que usases la función que te hice:

```
# obtengo la cantidad de vocales del nombre.
cvn = cant_vocales("Ernesto")

# obtengo la cantidad de vocales del apellido.
cva = cant_vocales("Salvador")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Dante. Tengo que contar las vocales porque así me lo pidió mi docente. Soy nuevo programando y tiendo a confundirme y me pierdo.